# Mezcla intercalada de dos arrays con diferente tamaño java

Tags: java, array

Buenas noches tengo una consulta como en el titulo yo tengo un método que crea un nuevo arreglo

```
public static void MezclaSS(int[] a, int[] b, int[] c, int na, int nb) {
    int Z = 0;

    for (int k = 0; k < na; k += 2) {
        c[k] = a[Z];
        c[k + 1] = b[Z];
    }
    for (int k = 0; k < nb; k += 2) {
        c[k] = a[Z];
        c[k + 1] = b[Z];
        Z++;
    }  

}
```

lo llamo de la siguiente manera

```
    int[] a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int[] b = {6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12};
    int[] c = new int[12];

    MezclaSS(a, b, c, 5, 7);
    for (int r = 0; r < 12; r++) {
        System.out.print(c[r] + ",");
```

Pero el resultado que obtengo es el siguiente
1,6,2,7,3,8,4,9,0,0,0,0

Pero el resultado que deseo es este:
1,6,2,7,3,8,4,9,5,10,11,12

No se que mas podría ser

Answer (score 1):

tomando en cuenta tu ejemplo y suponiendo que no tienes algun tipo de limitacion en cuanto a que tipo de bucle utilizar, lo hice de esta manera:

```
public static void MezclaSS(int[] a, int[] b, int[] c, int na, int nb) {    
    int c_i = 0; // iterador de c
    int b_i = 0; // iterador de b
    int a_i = 0; // iterador de a
    int nc = na + nb;   // limite de arreglo c

    while(c_i < nc) {
        if(a_i < na)
            c[c_i++] = a[a_i++];
        if(b_i < nb)
            c[c_i++] = b[b_i++];
    }
}
```

Lo he probado y me ha funcionado dando como resultado: 1,6,2,7,3,8,4,9,5,10,11,12,

Espero te sea de ayuda, y si tienes alguna duda no dudes en preguntar c:

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void MezclaSS(int[] a, int[] b, int[] c, int na, int nb) {
    int Z = 0;
    int pos=0;//posición de array c

    while (pos < na+nb) {
            if(Z < na){
               c[pos] = a[Z];
               pos++;
            }
            if(Z < nb){
                c[pos] = b[Z];
                pos++;
            }
            Z++;
    }
```

Esto sería Siguiendo tu código, pero te conviene usar el método `length` para conocer la **longitud** (cantidad de elementos) de cada array, o sea reemplazas `na` por `a.length` y `nb` por `b.length`, fijate que tambien te ahorras pasarle los argumentos o parámetros al método **MezclaSS**, además de antemano tenés que confiar que los valores de `na,nb` son correctos y también te evitas cambiar esos valores cada vez que modificas la longitud de cada array